# Perl:Shuffle an array 10 times, computing 10 average maxes, printing the mean average max. Repeat this entire process 1000 times

Tags: arrays, perl, bioinformatics

I have a data set which looks like the following

**1. Dataset**

```
NR_046018   DDX11L1 ,   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1      1    0   0   0   0   1.44    2.72    3.84    4.92
NR_047520   LOC643837   ,   3   2.2 0.2 0   0   0.28    1   1   1   1   2.2 4.8 5   5.32    5   5   5   5   3
NM_001005484    OR4F5   ,   2   2   2   1.68    1   0.48    0   0.92    1   1.8 2   2   2   2.04    3.88    3
NR_028327   LOC100133331    ,   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

**2. What is needed**

1. Shuffle the array 10 times. After *each* shuffle, divide the array into 2 new arrays, say *set1* and *set2*. (Half goes into *set1* and other half goes to *set2*)
2. From each new array, compute maximum value of each row of numbers, followed by an average max for all rows.
3. Get 10 average maxes of each *set1* and *set2*.(10 average maxes for 10 shuffles) Compute the average of the 10 average maxes obtained for *each* set, let's call it *10avg1* and *10avg2*.
4. Get a list of 1000 *10avg2* and 1000 *10avg2*.

**3.Code**

```
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(max shuffle);

my $file = 'mergesmall.txt';

#Open file and output file
open my $fh,'<',$file or die "Unable to open file";
open OUT,">Shuffle.out" or die;

#Read into array
my @arr = <$fh>;

#Intialize loop for shuffling 10 times
my $i=10;
while($i){
    my @arr1 = ();  #Intitialize 1st set
    my @arr2 = ();  #Initialize 2nd set

    my @shuffled = shuffle(@arr);

    push @arr1,(@shuffled[0..1]); #Shift into 1st set
    push @arr2,(@shuffled[2..3]); #Shift into 2nd set



    foreach $_(@arr1){
        my @val1 = split;
        my $max1 = max(@val1[3..$#val1]);

         $total1 += $max1;
         $num1++;
    }

    my $average_max1 = $total1 /  $num1;
    #print "\n\n","Average max 1st set is : ",$average_max1;
    print OUT "Average max 1st set is : ",$average_max1;

        foreach $_(@arr2){
        my @val2 = split;
        my $max2 = max(@val2[3..$#val2]);

        print "\n\n";

         $total2 += $max2;
         $num2++;
    }

    my $average_max2 =  $total2 /  $num2;
    #print "\n\n","Average max 2nd set is : ",$average_max2;
    print OUT "\n","Average max 2nd set is : ",$average_max2,"\n\n";


    $i--;

}
```

**4. The Problem**

The code I have been able to write so far can get 10 maximum averages of each *set1* and *set2*. I am not able to figure out how to compute the average of these 10 maximum averages. If I can figure out this, I can easily put a `for` loop to run 1000 times and obtain 1000 *10avgset1* and 1000 *10avgset2*

**5. Points to Note**

1. The actual data set has each row comprising a maximum of 400 numbers, some rows have less than that, some have none at all, but never more than 400.

2.The actual dataset has 41,382 rows. Set1 will comprise of 23,558 rows and set2 will comrpise of 17,824 rows.

3.File is a .txt file and all the numbers in each row are tab delimited.

I would be grateful if some idea could be provided as to how to compute average of maximum averages. I had thought of using `push @10avgset1, $average_max1` but I am not able to make it work.

Comment: What is the point shuffling 10 times?  Shouldn't it be random after the first shuffle (or at least the second shuffle)?

Comment: @Neil Basically, let's say we shuffle the main array once. We divide this shuffled array into 2 new sets of array,and compute average max for each set. Now we shuffle the main array a 2nd time and get a 2nd average max for each set. Likewise we get 10 average maxes for each set. Now from this list of 10 average maxes, the mean average is taken. This becomes mean average 1. We need 1000 mean averages.

Comment: The point is, we are trying to generate a control data set where the main array has been randomized as much as possible. I had thought it might be better to have a single shuffling done 1000 times(instead of 10 shufflings, getting an average value and repeating this 1000 times), but my supervisor wants it otherwise.

Comment: but still, either the first shuffle is random, or not. shuffling more times doesn't make it 'more random', I would guess...

Comment: @pavel Thank you for pointing that out. Would you suggest using the `rand` function then, seeding it like `srand(time|$$)` ? Is there any other way to randomize the array? The more random the array, the better will be the control set generated. Should I edit the question to "Randomize an array..." ?

Comment: minor comment: `use strict` will save you from headaches and you can import `max` and `shuffle` with `use List::Util qw(max shuffle)` instead of two lines.

Comment: @Neal: Your basic problem seems indeed to b: how do I insure a truly random shuffle. I don't know if `shuffle` suffices...

Comment: @pavel That is true. Since the original dataset contains over 40,000 rows, we are assuming that simply shuffling the array should result in sufficient randomization. Question is, do I shuffle it 1000 times together, or do bunches of 10 shufflings, and repeat that 1000 times. The former does appear a better option because repeating 10 shufflings 1000 times will likely generate the same dataset at least more than once isn't it?

Comment: @RobEarl Thank you Rob! I have noted it down. I skipped using `use strict` as I was just testing out a draft idea of getting the thing done. Perhaps I am better off using it even in my trial codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing I noted: You aren't using the `strict` pragma, and are in fact using global variables. I am not sure if that is what you want. Also, variables names may not start with a digit (in general).

Second thing I noted: You repeat yourself quite a lot.

Here is a function that does this weird "averaging of maxima" stuff:

```
use constant CARRY => 1; # set behaviour of original code;

sub make_accumulator {
    my $group = shift;
    my ($max, $num) = (0, 0) if CARRY;
    my @acc;
    my $acc = sub {
        my ($max, $num) = (0, 0) unless CARRY;
        for (@_) {
            $max += max @$_;
            $num++;
        }
        my $avg = $max / $num;
        push @acc, $avg;
        printf "Average max in set %d is %.2f\n", $group, $avg;
        $avg;
    };
    my $get = sub { @acc };
    ($acc, $get);
}
```

We can then do `my ($acc, $get) = make_accumulator(1)`, where `$acc` is a callback that encapsulates your algorithm, and `$get` returns the array of all such values computed so far.

A real average is computed with

```
sub average { sum(@_) / @_ }
```

To intitialize the script, I did

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(shuffle max sum);

use constant CARRY => 1;

my @arr = map {my @arr = split; [@arr[3..$#arr]]} <DATA>;

my ($acc1, $get1) = make_accumulator(1);
my ($acc2, $get2) = make_accumulator(2);
```

The line for `@arr` parses the line only once, during loading.
I then go on to loop a few times over shuffeled versions of `@arr`:

```
for (1 .. 5){
    my @shuffled = shuffle @arr;

    my $halfway = int (@shuffled / 2);
    my @arr1 = @shuffled[0 .. $halfway];
    my @arr2 = @shuffled[$halfway .. $#shuffled];

    my $average_max1 = $acc1->(@arr1);
    my $average_max2 = $acc2->(@arr2);

    printf "running: %.2f %.2f\n", average($get1->()), average($get2->());
    print "\n";
}
```

Here, I split the shuffeled list strictly into halves, you want to hardcode `23557` later. I then print the running averages for set1 and set2.

This produces output like:

```
Average max in set 1 is 2.93
Average max in set 2 is 4.60
running: 2.93 4.60

Average max in set 1 is 3.17
Average max in set 2 is 4.60
running: 3.05 4.60

Average max in set 1 is 3.09
Average max in set 2 is 4.60
mrunning: 3.07 4.60

Average max in set 1 is 3.17
Average max in set 2 is 4.55
running: 3.09 4.59

Average max in set 1 is 3.22
Average max in set 2 is 4.03
running: 3.12 4.48
```

If I set `CARRY` to a false value, I get

```
Average max in set 1 is 3.07
Average max in set 2 is 5.12
running: 3.07 5.12

Average max in set 1 is 3.07
Average max in set 2 is 2.46
running: 3.07 3.79

Average max in set 1 is 3.07
Average max in set 2 is 4.40
running: 3.07 3.99

Average max in set 1 is 3.41
Average max in set 2 is 4.40
running: 3.15 4.10

Average max in set 1 is 3.07
Average max in set 2 is 5.12
running: 3.14 4.30
```

This looks stupid, because there are only very few possible combinations of four lines (`n!/(n/2)!`, I guess).

Of course these values differ every time they are run, because `shuffle` already is pseudo-random.

#### Edit:

The `DATA` filehandle assumes that you have a data section at the end of the script like

```
__DATA__
NR_046018   DDX11L1 ,   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1      1    0   0   0   0   1.44    2.72    3.84    4.92
NR_047520   LOC643837   ,   3   2.2 0.2 0   0   0.28    1   1   1   1   2.2 4.8 5   5.32    5   5   5   5   3
NM_001005484    OR4F5   ,   2   2   2   1.68    1   0.48    0   0.92    1   1.8 2   2   2   2.04    3.88    3
NR_028327   LOC100133331    ,   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

To use whatever file is listed on the command line, do

```
my @arr = map {...} <>;  # no explicit filehandle
```

or open a file manually.

Comment: Hello amon! Many thanks for taking the time to peruse my question and providing a code. However, I am not quite able to follow the exact sequence of writing this code(I still am a newbie..). Would you be able to please elaborate a bit?

Comment: @Neal first comes the head, then the loop, then come the two subroutines. The constant declaration can be put into the header as well. The `make_accumulator` returns two anonymous surbroutines that are a closure over the `@acc` array. The `CARRY` constant employs conditional compilation of the `$max` and `$num` declarations. If it is *not* set, the anonymous accumulator only consideres the max values of the current input.

Comment: @Neal I changed a few lines so that the code should now be able to run on any perl. Please note my section with comments on the `DATA` filehandle at the end; you may have open your input file manually. If the errors persist, please post a comment with the error messages.

Comment: So sorry for the late reply, but I wasn't in the lab past 2 days.It is working great now! I've put the code in the same sequence as before and no errors this time. The concepts of `anonymous subroutines` and `CARRY` constant are a bit advanced for me. Where may I read more about them? Merry Christmas :)

Comment: @neal The [`perlsub`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) documentation covers [closures](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Persistent-Private-Variables) and [constant functions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Constant-Functions) that will be inlined and constant-folded. The `use constant` is syntactic sugar. `perlref` is valuable, especially the [section on metaprogramming](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Function-Templates). If you are seriously into Perl, looking at [Higher Order Perl](http://hop.perl.plover.com/) is a good idea, it discusses functional patterns for Perl.

Comment: Please note that this program maps well to object orientation too: My `make_accumulator` is a *constructor* for an object with two *methods* `acc` and `get`. This would be totally equivalent. The freaky conditional compilation would rather be modelled as subclassing.

I wrote the code in a functional style, because I could express the algorithms shorter and with less boilerplate code that way.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing me towards the correct documentations. I am mostly familiar with the procedural style of writing code in Perl, haven't actually started reading about the object oriented style. Since I am keen on Perl, and would be extensively using it in my internship over the next 6 months, I think I will give it a look as well. Happy new year to you in advance!